# Nginx not accepting more than 500-600 requests

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, load-testing, nginx-config

I am doing a load testing with nginx as a proxy server, it is not accepting the expected no of requests I guess, so I want to know whether I have to change any configuration in nginx.conf

I am using gatling tool for load testing. I am sending 1500 requests through gatling to nginx, but logs for only 500-600 requests will be generated in access log file. So I have a doubt that nginx only accepting 500 requests and rejecting all other. I dont know whether the problem is with nginx or gatling. So I want to know whether I have to increase any value in nginx conf file.How to make nginx to handle more requests.
Here is my nginx conf file

```
worker_processes  2;

events
{
#maximum number of connections for each worker process
worker_connections  2048;
}

#HTTP server

http
{
#allow underscores char in headers Eg : auth_token
underscores_in_headers on;

#Copying file attachment data into buffer to increase the server performance
sendfile        off;

# No. of seconds the server will wait before closing a keep-alive connection
keepalive_timeout  75;

#No. of requests a client can make over a single connection
keepalive_requests 50000;
   
# Maximum post size
client_max_body_size 30M;
   
#Maximum Request header size
client_header_buffer_size 2M;





proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     # Timeout for URL's - 2 hours
       proxy_read_timeout 120m;
         proxy_connect_timeout 120m;
          proxy_send_timeout 120m;
          proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
```

Comment: I faced the same issue, But I moved to HAProxy. I used it to handle 17K requests per second. I don't know I there are any configurations to improve Nginx performance.

Answer (score 0):

This my optimized Nginx file which handles 6500 plus requests.

```
user root;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    use                 epoll;
    worker_connections 65535;
    # multi_accept on;
    epoll_events        512;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    geoip_country /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoIP.dat; # the country IP database
    geoip_city    /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat; # the city IP database

    real_ip_recursive on;

    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
    set_real_ip_from 172.16.0.0/12;
    set_real_ip_from 192.168.0.0/16;
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
    #real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    log_format cloudflare '$http_cf_connecting_ip - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    client_body_temp_path  "/etc/nginx/tmp/client_body" 1 2;
    proxy_temp_path "/etc/nginx/tmp/proxy" 1 2;
    
    scgi_temp_path "/etc/nginx/tmp/scgi" 1 2;
    uwsgi_temp_path "/etc/nginx/tmp/uwsgi" 1 2;

    ##
    # Define fastcgi_cache settings
    ##

    fastcgi_temp_path "/etc/nginx/tmp/fastcgi" 1 2;
    fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=phpcache:360m inactive=24h max_size=256M;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$cookie_pll_language";
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_503;
    fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
    fastcgi_buffers 256 32k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 4s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 120s;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 512k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 512K;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $http_host;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_cache_lock on;
    fastcgi_cache_lock_age 1s;
    fastcgi_cache_lock_timeout 3s;

    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout          600;
    proxy_read_timeout          600;
    

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    # if client stop responding, free up memory -- default 60
    send_timeout 120;

    # server will close connection after this time -- default 75
    keepalive_timeout 90;

    # number of requests client can make over keep-alive -- for testing environment
    keepalive_requests 1024;

    # if the request body size is more than the buffer size, then the entire (or partial)
    
    # request body is written into a temporary file
    client_body_buffer_size  10k;

    # buffer size for reading client request header -- for testing environment
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;

    # maximum number and size of buffers for large headers to read from client request
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

    # read timeout for the request body from client -- for testing environment
    client_body_timeout   32;

    # how long to wait for the client to send a request header -- for testing environment
    client_header_timeout 32;

    client_max_body_size 80M;

    server_tokens off;
    port_in_redirect off;
    access_log off;
```

let me know if this works for you. its not in full but the part which you need.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?